# How can i check my created namespace?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-namespaces

Using `clone()` or `unshare()`, we can create a network namespace. Just as the command:

```
ns_exec -nm -- /bin/bash
```

(see http://lxc.sourceforge.net/index.php/about/kernel-namespaces/network/configuration/)

If I have created several network namespaces with `ns_exec` command, where can I see them? or
How can i count the numbers of network namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You observe them indirectly. Say, lo devices are independent, iptables rules are independent and so on.

netns objects live in it's own kmem_cache:
grep net_namespace /proc/slabinfo

But this is unreliable way to count them, as SLUB can share caches.

There is no /proc file or something dedicated specifically as netns counter.

Comment: Why is net_namespace record in /proc/slabinfo unreliable? using ns_exec to create new network namespace, and slabinfo shows:     grep net_namespace /proc/slabinfo
net_namespace  1 3 2112 3 2 : tunables 24 12 8 : slabdata  1  1 0  active_objs is 1, and num_objs is 3. active_objs value is what i expected. but i'm double why num_objs is 3. I only created a new network namespace.

Comment: SLUB can merge caches if sizeof() matches + some addtitional conditions. So, the number of objects slabinfo shows is sum of all objects from merged caches.

SLAB doesn't merge, and user can have any slab allocator, so you can't rely on it.